# I have run a job based on the changes in repository,

Tags: maven, jenkins, automation

Problem: I have an jenkins job that runs based on scheduled time, I wanted to do a change like If the developer does some changes in their repository my job has to run. Example: If developer push code to their repo my Jenkins job has to pull the code from automation repo and has to run the job. Right now I have given my automation git repo URL so it will do pull at the scheduled time and run the job, But how to configure the job to check the developer repo to run job?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a build based on developers repo and in successful post build action, trigger automation build.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below article:

https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github/